# How to transfer or delete a Google Scholar profile from my own account?

Tags: website, google-scholar

I accidentally created my advisor's Google scholar profile using my personal Gmail. Now I can't find a way to transfer the profile to him, nor can I delete his profile in my account.

Does anyone have any idea what to do?

This is almost a tech support question, but since it's so unique to academics I figure I should ask here.

I tried to look at the [Google product forum](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/en), but there is no forum for Google Scholar. They don't have a support line for Google Scholar either. I have not found a way even after posting on the Google product forum. I'm truly stuck.

Comment: Have you asked Google yet? It is a tech support question for them.

Comment: @BillBarth I tried to look at Google product forum https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/en, but there is no forum for Google scholar. They don't have a support line for Google scholar either. Do you have any idea where I may ask?

Comment: If anyone is coming here for update, I have not found a way even after posting on Google product forum. I'm truly stuck.

Comment: As far as I know, this is still an issue in 2023. That's insane. And to think that some fields use google scholar for their hiring / promotion process…

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Google Scholar profiles are not transferable. But you *can* delete the Google Scholar profile from your own account. Then create a new profile while signed in to your advisor's account.

To delete the Scholar profile from your own account, go to [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com) and click on "Settings":

[image]

then click on "Account":

[image]

then click on "Delete or recover your Scholar account."

There, you'll have to affirm that you are sure you'd like to delete the account, and that you understand you have 30 days to change your mind. Check all the boxes, then click "Delete account":

[image]

Comment: Opinion that doesn't add to the discussion: this is stupid. What are researchers supposed to do if they leave academia, permanently or temporarily? Google scholar is a way of displaying researchers' personal data and published papers. That's fine, but once you leave academia, you essentially lose all control of this process and you can no longer manage the account. This just seems like a very poorly thought out network.